# Help to find the physical pattern, related to eigenvalues of multivectors (possibly hard)

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, physics, clifford-algebras

Let $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2$ and $\mathbf{u}$ be a multivector of $Cl_4(\mathbb{C})$:

---

Example #1 :

$\mathbf{v}_1=t\gamma_0+x\gamma_1+y\gamma_2+z\gamma_3$

The matrix representation of $\mathbf{v}_1$, using the gamma matrices is:

$$
\pmatrix{t&0&z&x-iy\\0&t&x+iy&-z\\-z&-x+iy&-t&0\\-x-iy&z&0&-t}
$$

The two unique eigenvalues of this matrix are $\lambda=\pm\sqrt{t^2-x^2-y^2-z^2}$, which we recognize as the interval of special relativity.

---

Example #2 :

$\mathbf{v}_2=E_1\gamma_0\gamma_1+E_2\gamma_0\gamma_1+E_3\gamma_0\gamma_3+B_1\gamma_2\gamma_3+B_2\gamma_1\gamma_3+B_3\gamma_1\gamma_2$

The four unique eigenvalues of its matrix representation are $\lambda=\pm\sqrt{-B_1^2-B_2^2-B_3^2+E_1^2+E_2^2+E_3^2\pm2\sqrt{-(B_1 E_1+B_2E_2+B_3E_3)^2}}$. It is also quite interesting, because if we write $\mathbf{E}=(E_1,E_2,E_3)$ and $\mathbf{B}=(B_1,B_2,B_3)$, we can write the eigenvalues as:

$$
\lambda =\pm \sqrt{-||\mathbf{B}||^2+||\mathbf{E}||^2\pm 2i \mathbf{B}\cdot \mathbf{E}}
$$

These are simply the two Lorentz invariants of electromagnetism.

---

So in each case, there is a physical interpretation to the eigenvalues of the multivector.

---

Now, I am trying to look at more complicated cases and see if there is even more physics to be found. Specifically, I am looking at the interference pattern found within the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{v}_1+\mathbf{v}_2$, or:

$$
\mathbf{u}=t\gamma_0+x\gamma_1+y\gamma_2+z\gamma_3+E_1\gamma_0\gamma_1+E_2\gamma_0\gamma_1+E_3\gamma_0\gamma_3+B_1\gamma_2\gamma_3+B_2\gamma_1\gamma_3+B_3\gamma_1\gamma_2
$$

The matrix representation of $\mathbf{u}$, using the gamma matrices, is:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 t-i \text{B3} & -\text{B2}+(-i) \text{B1} & \text{E3}+z & \text{E1}-i \text{E2}+x-i y \\
 \text{B2}-i \text{B1} & t+i \text{B3} & \text{E1}+i \text{E2}+x+i y & -\text{E3}-z \\
 \text{E3}-z & \text{E1}-i \text{E2}-x+i y & -t-i \text{B3} & -\text{B2}+(-i) \text{B1} \\
 \text{E1}+i \text{E2}-x-i y & z-\text{E3} & \text{B2}-i \text{B1} & -t+i \text{B3} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and the eigenvalues are too verbose and Mathematica nearly gives up, but manually, we can find a pattern. Let $||\mathbf{s}||^2$ be the interval of special relativity. Then eigenvalues of $\mathbf{u}$ are:

$$
\lambda=\pm\sqrt{-||\mathbf{B}||^2+||\mathbf{E}||^2+||\mathbf{s}||^2\pm 2i\sqrt{(\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{E})^2 + \text{interference-pattern}}}
$$

As we can see, it is a unification of the two previous results, but with the addition of a complicated "interference-pattern" between the two. My question is what is the physical meaning of this interference pattern?

---

Let me give the interference pattern explicitly:

$$
-B_1^2 t^2 - B_2^2 t^2 - B_3^2 t^2 + 2 B_3 E_2 t x - 2 B_2 E_3 t x + 
 B_1^2 x^2 - E_2^2 x^2 - E_3^2 x^2 - 2 B_3 E_1 t y + 2 B_1 E_3 t y + 
 2 B_1 B_2 x y + 2 E_1 E_2 x y + B_2^2 y^2 - E_1^2 y^2 - E_3^2 y^2 + 
 2 B_2 E_1 t z - 2 B_1 E_2 t z + 2 B_1 B_3 x z + 2 E_1 E_3 x z + 
 2 B_2 B_3 y z + 2 E_2 E_3 y z + B_3^2 z^2 - E_1^2 z^2 - E_2^2 z^2
$$

---

Trying to "organize" it a little bit I get (I pose $\mathbf{x}=(x,y,z)$):

$$
-t^2 ||\mathbf{B}||^2 + (\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{B})^2 - (E_2 x-E_1 y)^2-(E_3 x- E_1z )^2-(E_3 y -E_2z)^2 - 2t \det \pmatrix{x&y&z\\B_1&B_2&B_3\\E_1&E_2&E_3}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example **v**$_1$ is straightforward, and perhaps you'd wish to see a pattern in it to generalize to the rest.

Gamma matrices are special, in that any [odd power of them is traceless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Trace_identities), and the traces of its square and 4th power are trivial, so for your $ {\mathbf v}_1=X\cdot \gamma$, the corresponding traces are trivial functions of the interval,
$$
\operatorname{Tr} {\mathbf v}^2_1 = 4 X^2 , \qquad \operatorname{Tr} {\mathbf v}^4_1 = 4 (X^2)^2.
$$

These 4×4 matrices then have a simple characteristic polynomial found by the virtually collapsing 
[Faddeev–LeVerrier algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev%E2%80%93LeVerrier_algorithm),
$$
p(\lambda)= \det (\lambda I - {\mathbf v}_1  )= \det {\mathbf v}_1 -\frac{\lambda^2}{2} \operatorname{Tr} {\mathbf v}^2_1 +\lambda^4 ,
$$
while the determinant of the leading term is famously evident from the algorithm -- but also the trace of the [C-H theorem expression for a general 4×4 matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem#Determinant_and_inverse_matrix) ,
$$
4\det {\mathbf v}_1= \tfrac{1}{2}  (\operatorname{Tr} {\mathbf v}^2_1)^2 -  \operatorname{Tr} {\mathbf v}^4_1,
$$ 
so that
$$
p(\lambda) = (\lambda^2 - X^2)^2,
$$
with the double roots you found.

Perhaps this might inspire you for the further cases. The general theme is that *traces of powers* are simpler to evaluate than other invariants: we are back to Cayley's [theory of invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_theory) and Hilbert's molding of it!

Comment: So, in the case of an arbitrary 4x4 complex matrix, are you suggesting that instead of trying to find $det M$ the usual way (which is hard), I can simply apply the formula $4 \det = \frac{1}{2}(\Tr M^2)^2-\Tr M^4$? If so then its really absolutely amazing.

Comment: Careful!  Here the magic of vanishing traces of odd powers was used. For a most general 4x4 matrix, $\det A=   \tfrac{1}{24} \left ( (\operatorname{tr}A)^4-6 \operatorname{tr}(A^2)(\operatorname{tr}A)^2+3(\operatorname{tr}(A^2))^2+8\operatorname{tr}(A^3)\operatorname{tr}(A) -6\operatorname{tr}(A^4) \right )$, as you learn from the [C-H theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley–Hamilton_theorem#Determinant_and_inverse_matrix).

Comment: ... but, trust me, no time lavished on appreciating the Faddeev-LeVerrier algorithm is ever wasted...