# The eigenvalues of a multivector

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, algebraic-geometry, clifford-algebras

Since multivectors have a matrix representation, then they should have eigenvalues. In the case of matrices, the characteristic polynomial is defined as:

$$
\det[\lambda I-M]=0
$$

How can I define the characteristic polynomial of a multivector, without referencing the notion of matrices? What is the general procedure to construct the characteristic polynomial without leaving the geometric algebra world?

---

Edit:

For instance, in $Cl_3(\mathbb{R})$, represented by the Pauli matrices, the multivector:

$$
\mathbf{v}=a+x\sigma_x+y\sigma_y+z\sigma_z
$$

has the following matrix representation:

$$
V=\pmatrix{a+z&x-iy\\x+iy&a-z}
$$

and its eigenvalues are $\lambda=a\pm\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

The question then becomes, how do I construct, using geometric operations, a polynomial such that its roots are $\lambda$ starting from $\mathbf{v}$ and without converting to matrices, for any multivector of any geometric algebra. Also, how do I adapt the definition $\det[\lambda I-M]=0$ to refer only to geometry, without matrices?

For example, taking the geometric product I get:

$$
\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}=(a+x\sigma_x+y\sigma_y+z\sigma_z)(a+x\sigma_x+y\sigma_y+z\sigma_z)\\
=a^2+x^2+y^2+z^2+2a(x\sigma_x+y\sigma_y+z\sigma_z)\\
=a^2+x^2+y^2+z^2+2a(x\sigma_x+y\sigma_y+z\sigma_z+a-a)\\
=a^2+x^2+y^2+z^2+2a(\mathbf{v}-a)\\
=-a^2+x^2+y^2+z^2+2a\mathbf{v}\\
\implies \mathbf{v}^2-2a\mathbf{v}+a^2-x^2-y^2-z^2=0\\
\implies \mathbf{v}=a\pm\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}
$$

The procedure creates the characteristic polynomial at the line $\mathbf{v}^2=a^2+x^2+y^2+z^2+2a(\mathbf{v}-a)$, when all basis elements are erased or hidden behind $\mathbf{v}$ of different degrees.

I am able to work it out in a handful of specific cases.

In $Cl_4$ specifically, the polynomial would have to be of degree 4.

Comment: Can you say a bit more about the matrix representation about a multivector? Are you referring specifically to the matrix representation of a bivector? If not, could you provide a definition or point to a reference?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom done! Please check the edit.

Comment: One approach is to define a linear map associated with an element $\mathbf v$ in your Clifford algebra, so that the characteristic polynoimal you want is the characteristic polynomial of this linear map.  In particular, I believe that associating $\mathbf v$ with the linear map $\mathbf w \mapsto \langle \mathbf v, \mathbf w \rangle$ gives you a suitable representation. Note that $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the symmetric bilinear form associated with the quadratic form of the Clifford algebra.

Comment: Actually, I think the above can only yield a suitable representation if the quadratic form is non-degenerate

Comment: @Omnomnomnom As far as I can tell, the bilinear form approach only works for 1-vectors and/or k-vectors. But as soon as you mix blades of different grades, the bilinear form no longer outputs a scalar, so you have to use the replacements as shown in my example and this requires the construction of a general polynomial; for example 2=2+2+2+2+2(−). In the case of CL_3 This polynomial contains both degree 2 (2) and degree 1 (), but in the case of CL_4, the polynomial will contain all degress of  between 1 and 4: it is a general quartic polynomial.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Or maybe what you are suggesting is that I should simply identify the correct characteristic polynomial using the matrix representation, then simply use it to define a new bilinear form for my multivectors, producing an entirely geometric algebra-based definition for the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3688668/help-to-find-the-physical-pattern-related-to-eigenvalues-of-multivectors-possi/3690144#3690144).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinants of low dimensional matrices, especially your 2×2 ones, are easiest gotten from traces through the combinatorics of the [Jacobi formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula).

In particular, by the  [Faddeev–LeVerrier algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev%E2%80%93LeVerrier_algorithm), you get, for such 2×2 matrices,  a characteristic polynomial
$$
p(\lambda)= \lambda^2 -\lambda \operatorname{Tr} M +\frac{1}{2} ( (\operatorname{Tr} M)^2 - \operatorname{Tr} M^2).
$$
So, for $M= \mathbf v$, you have just 
$$
p(\lambda) = (\lambda-a)^2-r^4, 
$$
etc, in an evident recursive structure. I assume you can work it out?